# Bit array AND in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a grid something like this:

```
  A A A A A
B C C C C C
B C C C C C
B C C C C C
B C C C C C
B C C C C C
```

Each `A` and `B` are numeric values derived from creating a bit array from some other work going on elsewhere in the worksheets.

In `C`, I need to perform a bitwise AND on the intersecting `A` and `B` and test if the result is greater than zero (i.e., there's at least one matching bit value of "1").

This **must** be a pure Excel formula, can't use macros--it is used in a conditional format. Using macros to simulate conditional formatting is not an option, nor is creating a table that duplicates `C` and uses a macro to store the answer that the conditional formatting can look at.

The values for `A` and `B` could be stored as a string with 1's and 0's if some string magic is easier to perform.

Any ideas?

**edit**

The accepted answer gives me what I need, but for posterity, here's how to extend it to extend that solution to give bitwise answers back:

```
AND = SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(VALUE($A2)+VALUE(B$1),"1","0"),"2","1")
OR = SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(VALUE($A2)+VALUE(B$1),"2","1")
XOR = SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(VALUE($A2)+VALUE(B$1),"2","0")
```

Comment: The number of bits in A and B are the same, but not fixed. Will range from 1 to ~30, depending on the spreadsheet (the sheet is generated on the server and the number of bits varies from one export to another).

Comment: I'm just curious as to why no VBA here. Is it just a speed thing? You can certainly write a VBA function and call it from a conditional format rule.

Comment: @jtolle: My Excel files are server-generated by a custom XML Spreadsheet library or binary via NPOI, and thus can't contain macros. My users have an add-in installed with utility functions, but if I attempt to call an add-in function from a conditional formatting rule, I get the error "You may not use references to other worksheets or workbooks for Conditional Formatting criteria." However, the formats can refer to a cell that is then dependent on the add-in function that creates the bit arrays for A and B.

Comment: I like the summary. If the dec2bin and bin2dec are available by default, which I think is the case for newer versions, we would have true bitwise operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

save it as a string of 0 and 1, add them as numbers together, convert that to string and look for a 2.

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("2",TEXT(VALUE($A2)+VALUE(B$1),"0")))
```

copy in cell B2 with data in A2 and B1, then copy&paste around.

**edit:** Wow! they have put in a function DEC2BIN()!

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("2",TEXT(VALUE(DEC2BIN($A2))+VALUE(DEC2BIN(B$1)),"0")))
```

and leave them numbers.

Comment: Elegant. Love it. DEC2BIN() is only available with the Analysis ToolPak add-in, but the first example will do the trick. Edited to add some detail for actually implementing Boolean operators.

Comment: Follow-up question: I would expect FIND() to be faster than SEARCH() since FIND() is case-sensitive and has no wildcard support. Any particular reason for SEARCH()? Also, FIND/SEARCH will implicitly convert the sum of A and B to a string, so no need for TEXT().

Comment: I have a basic ms office installed on a mac - nothing special. maybe newer versions come with dec2bin? as for find/search, sounds like you could be right. But in excel, when performance comes into play, run away!

Comment: One issue found-- since the number is being stored in decimal, only up to 15 digits are supported. After that Excel loses significant digits trying to add the numbers.

Comment: try to mix in 3 bits per digit then ;-)

Comment: My tentative solution is to test LEFT(bits,15) and RIGHT(bits,15), which will get me up to 30 bits without much performance pain (using IF() to shortcut).

Answer (score 0):

What about `=(A + B) > 0` if you're doing OR (which you're describing) or `=(A + B) > 1` if you're doing AND (like you're actually writing).

Comment: `2 & 1 == 0` vs. `(2 + 1) > 0`